# Create new array from MySQL query

Tags: php

I'd like to create new array with IDs where users have access to sector.

```
$sector = '60';
```

Create new array with User IDs (2 and 4) in this case...

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT user_id, user_sectors FROM admin_users"); 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        $id[] = $row[user_id]; 
        $sectors[] = unserialize(base64_decode($row[user_sectors])); 
    }   

$combine = array_combine($id, $sectors);
print "<pre>";
print_r($combine);
print "</pre>";

Array
(
[2] => Array <<<<<<<<<< USER ID
    (
        [0] => 49 <<<<<<<<<< SECTORS
        [1] => 60
        [2] => 69
        [3] => 65
        [4] => 66
        [5] => 59
        [6] => 71
        [7] => 57
    )

[3] => Array <<<<<<<<<< USER ID
    (
        [0] => 49 <<<<<<<<<< SECTORS
    )

[4] => Array <<<<<<<<<< USER ID
    (
        [0] => 49 <<<<<<<<<< SECTORS
        [1] => 60
        [2] => 65
        [3] => 58
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `user_id` as the key of the array and append `[]` an array item with the `user_sectors`:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $sectors[$row['user_id']][] = unserialize(base64_decode($row['user_sectors']));
}
```

That being said, for `mysql_*()` functions:

> **Warning** This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension
>   should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ
>   for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
>
> - mysqli_fetch_array()
> - PDOStatement::fetch()